# How to get localized city and country names for timezone name

Tags: ios, localization, nsdateformatter, nslocalizedstring, nstimezone

How can I get city name and country name from timezone?
For example, I can see all knownTimeZoneNames array, and I want to show in labels "Europe/Moscow" as "Moscow, Russia" in few languages. How can I get this strings?
Actually I need localized list, as in Clock.app in iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

You can get country name from city name like this:

first import the Core Location framework

```
CLGeocoder *gc = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init]; 
[gc geocodeAddressString:@"Moscow" 
    completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) 
    { CLPlacemark *placeMark = [[CLPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:(CLPlacemark *)[placemarks objectAtIndex:0]]; NSLog(@"placeMark.country: %@", placeMark.country); 
    }
];
```

Comment: can i got list of the city from the country name in ios?

Comment: can anyone help translating this to swift?